# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart

Tags: flutter

please how can i solve this problem
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.",

Comment: did you add `firebase_analytics` to `pubspec.yaml`? If so, did you run from the command line `flutter packages get`?

Comment: yes i added firebase analytics to pubspec.yaml and i have run the command line flutter packages get